# Why existance of layout and layout-normal-mdpi does not produce compile-time error?

Tags: android, android-layout

A naked `layout` resource directory Android OS interprets as `layout, normal, mdpi`, according to the docs. If I create a new project and make layout structure like this:

```
/res/
    /layout/
    /layout-normal/
```

OR

```
/res/
    /layout/
    /layout-normal-mdpi/
```

I get no error. Why?

If there is no error, then I can conclude that naked `layout` directory **is not** `normal, mdpi`, but it's for all those layout which were not explicitly set, right?! So its purpose is always variable?!

In example no.2., if I load the content on `normal, mdpi` mobile screen, will it load from the naked or explicit directory?

Thanks in advance anyone taking time to clarify this for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The app may be running on a device that disqualifies the `/layout-normal-mdpi` resources from consideration. It will then fall back on the resources in `/layout`. In other words, the resources in `/layout` will be used as the default for any configuration that has no more specific resource available.

It makes a bit more sense to talk about drawables. The system will scale drawables from `/drawable` from the default `mdpi` to the density of the actual configuration. The `/drawable-mdpi` resources, on the other hand, will be used specifically for `mdpi` configurations.

Comment: That what I was afraid of. So bare `layout` is not `layout-normal-mdpi`. It's just default. Am I right?

Comment: @sandalone - It's just default for all configurations. (Just as `/layout-large-mdpi` is the default for large, mdpi screens in all languages, etc.) Some resources are scaled or otherwise adjusted to the actual configuration by assuming they were specified for large, mdpi screens.